# How many Scope's are there in an angularApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is that how many scope elements would be in the below code including isolatedScope, $scope, $rootScope.

```
 <script>
          angular.module('initExample', [])
            .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
              $scope.list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']];
            }]);
        </script>
       <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
          <div ng-repeat="innerList in list" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
            <div ng-repeat="value in innerList" ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
               <span class="example-init">list[ {{outerIndex}} ][ {{innerIndex}} ] = {{value}};</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: what about ng-repeat and ng-init?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be a `$rootScope`,
then there would be Controller `scope`, from `ExampleController`,

then, since `ng-repeat` creates a new `scope` for every row, so outer `ng-repeat` would create `list.length` scopes, `ng-init` would not create a new scope, 
Now the internal `ng-repeat` runs once for each outer `ng-repeat`, so it would create `innerList.length` scopes for each list item.

so, total scopes would be : `$rootScope` + `$scope` from Controller + `list.length` * `innerList.length`.

So total in this case 1 + 1 + 2 * 2 = 6.

(I am not sure why this information is required, but here it is).

P.S: you can check the documentation to know which `directive`s create a new(isolated) `scope`.
Also note that, if the innerList has variable length for each list item, then the formula would include summation of innerList lengths over outerlist length and not a direct multiplication,

i.e, ( 1 * i1 + 1 * i2 + ... outerlist.length times ), where i1,i2 are inner list lengths

Comment: ng-repeat doesn't create an isolated scope for each row. Each directive has it's own scope. 2 ng-repeat = 2 scopes

Comment: @gyc from the documentation: The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope

Comment: Thanks @gaurav5430 for explaining this in simple way :) 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L3